# When trying to compare two dataframes element-wise, it returns false result for some columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, compare

I have two dataframes: t1 and t2
First column is object and second is int64:

[image: Datatypes]

In the first column all the values are the same and in the second column all tha values are different.

t1:

[image]

t2:

[image]

When I try to comapre the dataframes element-wise I expect to return true where the elements are equal and false where they are not equal. However the result is also true for the second column. Why is this happening and how can this be tackled?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[pandas.DataFrame.lt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) means less than.

`df1['kzfsp_x']` is equal with `df2['kzfsp_y']` rather less than, so `df1['kzfsp_x'].lt(df2['kzfsp_y'].values)` is False.

```
df1['kzfsp_x'].lt(df2['kzfsp_y'].values)

0    False
1    False
2    False
Name: kzfsp_x, dtype: bool
```

Also, values in `df1['kzbzerl_x']` is greater than `df2['kzbzerl_y']`, not less than, so `df1['kzbzerl_x'].lt(df2['kzbzerl_y'].values)` is False.

```
df1['kzbzerl_x'].lt(df2['kzbzerl_y'].values)

0    False
1    False
2    False
Name: kzbzerl_x, dtype: bool
```